# Failed to generate code for the service reference 'RouteService'.in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have developed a wp7 app,
and i have upgraded that into wp8.

when i build the app it shows the following error

1)Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'RouteService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.

2)Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'GeoCodecService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.

I tried, delete that service references and added that again, but no use.
how can i solve this errors.
Can anybody help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the new API's for Wp8, they are very easy:

for routing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244363(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_showroute

and check this for all other functions: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html